# Evaluate the indefinite integral of $\int\left(a^2-\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}-a\cos{(a)}\right)\,da$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the indefinite integral

$$\int\left(a^2-\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}-a \cos {(a)}\right)\,da$$

I tried a lot of integration strategies to solve this, but I can't find what will solve the derivative. Can you give me a hint on how to solve this?

Specifically, I am thinking that the fact that

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}\,dx = \tan^{-1} (x) + C$$

can be applied here.

Let me share my solution

$$\int\left(a^2-\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}-a \cos {(a)}\right)\,da =\int\frac{a^2(a^2-1)-\sin {(a)}-a(a^2-1) \cos {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}\,da$$

$$=\int\frac{a^4 -a^3\cos {(a)}- a^2+a\cos {(a)}-\sin {(a)} }{a^{2} + 1}\,da$$

I got stuck here. I hope you can help me solve the problem.
Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: The title and the body are diferent. Both are trivial, isn't? Just check carefuly the integration variable.

Comment: Thank you @azif00 for your comment. The given was already edited.

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica: $\frac{a^3}{3}-\frac{e^2 \text{Ci}(i-a)-\text{Ci}(i-a)+e^2 \text{Ci}(a+i)-\text{Ci}(a+i)+e^2 i \text{Si}(i-a)+i \text{Si}(i-a)+e^2 i \text{Si}(a+i)+i \text{Si}(a+i)}{4 e}-a \sin (a)-\cos (a)$ Maple: $\frac{a^{3}}{3}-\cos(a)-a \sin(a)+\frac{\mathrm{I} (\mathrm{Si}(a-\mathrm{I}) \cosh(1)+\mathrm{I} \,\mathrm{Ci}(a-\mathrm{I}) \sinh(1))}{2}-\frac{\mathrm{I} (\mathrm{Si}(a+\mathrm{I}) \cosh(1)-\mathrm{I} \,\mathrm{Ci}(a+\mathrm{I}) \sinh(1))}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int\left(a^2-\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}-a\cos{(a)}\right)\,da=\int\left(a^2-a\cos{(a)}\right)\,da-\int\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}\,da$$ The first integral does not make any problem.

Considering the second
$$\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a^{2} + 1}=\frac{\sin {(a)}}{(a+i)(a-i)}=\frac i 2\left( \frac{\sin {(a)}}{a+i}-\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a-i}\right)$$ Let us consider
$$I_k=\int\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a+ki}\,da\qquad \text{with}\qquad k=\pm 1$$ make $b=a+ki$, replace and expand the sine function
$$I_k=\int\frac{\sin {(a)}}{a+ki}\,da=\int\frac{\sin (b-i k)}{b}\,db=\int \frac{\sin (b) \cosh (k)-i \cos (b) \sinh (k)}{b}\,db$$
$$I_k=\cosh (k)\int\frac{\sin (b)}b \,db-i\sinh (k)\int\frac{\cos (b)}b \,db$$
$$I_k=\cosh (k)\,\text{Si}(b)-i\sinh (k)\,\text{Ci}(b)$$ where appear the sine and cosine exponential integral functions.

Comment: Indeed: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1406448.